# check if string is in list while table definition

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I'm looking for a translation to [Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/index.html) for a [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/) command.
It looks pretty simple, but I couldn't find anything around to implement this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  type varchar (50) NOT NULL,
  ...
  location varchar(25) check (location in ('north', 'south', 'west', 'east')),
  ...
  created date      
);
```

How would you define the line
`location varchar(25) check (location in ('north', 'south', 'west', 'east', 'northeast', 'southeast', 'southwest', 'northwest'))`
in Slick?

I'm interested in applying those checks for string sanity at db level
(I currently do them at code level)

Any help welcome!

Comment: Slick supports `primary key` (needed for insert/update/join) and `foreign key` constraints (for join). I think that general constraints would be difficult to encode, and not necessary at all. You have no use for them in Scala code? Although you could use raw queries to add a constraint, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be better to create ENUM type? Consider this work around.

```
CREATE TYPE location AS ENUM (
    'north',
    'south',
    'west',
    'east'
);

CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  type varchar (50) NOT NULL,
  ...
  location location,
  ...
  created date      
);
```